Killing Vectors AdS$_3$
I have been trying to understand the Killing vectors of AdS$_3$,i.e. Anti de Sitter in three dimension:
$$
ds^2 = dX^2 + dY^2 -dU^2 -dV^2
$$
In this case the generators are given by $J_{ab}=x_a \partial_b -x_b \partial_a$ and the Killing vectors corresponds to
$$
\xi^0 = \frac{1}{2} \left( J_{01} +J_{23} \right) \\
\xi^1 = \frac{1}{2} \left( J_{02} +J_{13} \right) \\
\xi^2 = \frac{1}{2} \left( J_{03} -J_{12} \right)
$$
For the $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ left and for the $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ right
$$
\eta^0 = \frac{1}{2} \left( J_{01} -J_{23} \right) \\
\eta^1 = \frac{1}{2} \left( J_{02} -J_{13} \right) \\
\eta^2 = \frac{1}{2} \left( J_{03} +J_{12} \right).
$$
The reference is Coussaert and Henneaux.
However when I work in a different set of coordinates like in this article the Killing vectors are
$$
J_1 = - \frac{2\sinh\sigma}{\cosh \omega} \partial_\tau - 2\cosh \sigma \partial_\omega + 2 \tanh \omega \sinh \sigma \partial_\sigma \\
J_2 = 2\partial_\sigma \\
J_0 =  \frac{2\cosh\sigma}{\cosh \omega} \partial_\tau + 2\sinh \sigma \partial_\omega - 2 \tanh \omega \cosh \sigma \partial_\sigma 
$$
and
$$
\tilde{J}_1 = 2 \sin \tau \tanh \omega \partial_\tau - 2\cos \tau \partial_\omega +\frac{2\sin \tau}{\cosh \omega} \partial_\sigma \\
\tilde{J}_2 = 2 \cos \tau \tanh \omega \partial_\tau - 2\sin \tau \partial_\omega -\frac{2\cos \tau}{\cosh \omega} \partial_\sigma \\
\tilde{J}_0 =  2 \partial_\tau
$$
where in theory the metric in this case is
$$
ds^2 = \frac{1}{4} \left(-d\tau^2 + d\omega^2 +d\sigma^2 \right) + \cosh\frac{\omega}{2} \sinh \frac{\omega}{2}
$$
Now, my question: How can I get these Killing vectors? because I obtain the following KV
$$
\xi_1 = e^{-u} \left(-\frac{1}{\cosh \sigma} \partial_\tau + \partial_\sigma + \tanh\sigma \partial_\mu \right) \\
\xi_2 = e^u \left(\frac{1}{\cosh \sigma} \partial_\tau + \partial_\sigma - \tanh\sigma \partial_\mu \right) \\
\xi_3 = \tanh \sigma \cos \tau \partial_\tau + \sin \tau \partial_\sigma + \frac{\cos \tau}{\cosh \sigma} \partial_\mu \\
\xi_4 = -\tanh \sigma \sin \tau \partial_\tau + \cos \tau \partial_\sigma - \frac{\sin \tau}{\cosh \sigma} \partial_\mu \\
\xi_5 = \partial_\tau \\
\xi_6 = \partial_u
$$
where the metric in this case is
$$ 
ds^2 = -\cosh^2 \sigma d\tau^2 + d\sigma^2 + (du +\sinh\sigma d\tau)^2
$$
Note: I am using Maple to find KV.

I found the solution to this problem
In my KV I can do the following
$$
\xi_1= - \frac{\sinh{u}}{\cosh \sigma} \partial_\tau + \cosh{u} \partial_\sigma - \tanh{\sigma} \sinh{u} \partial_u + \frac{\cosh{u}}{\cosh{\sigma}} \partial_\tau - \sinh{u} \partial_\sigma + \tanh{\sigma} \cosh{u} \partial_u \\
\xi_2= - \frac{\cosh{u}}{\cosh \sigma} \partial_\tau + \sinh{u} \partial_\sigma - \tanh{\sigma} \cosh{u} \partial_u - \frac{\sinh{u}}{\cosh{\sigma}} \partial_\tau + \cosh{u} \partial_\sigma - \tanh{\sigma} \sinh{u} \partial_u 
$$
Since the combination of KV is a KV, then we can do
$$
\chi^1 = \frac{\xi_1 + \xi_2}{2} \\
\chi^2 = \frac{\xi_1 - \xi_2}{2}
$$
and with these combination we will get the result that I was looking for.
